# Store nested JSON object as a string C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, nested-json

I ran into an issue when parsing JSON . I am parsing JSON similar to this :

```
{
  "regularProperty" : "Test here",
  "nestedJSON" : {
    "propertyText1" : "new Text",
    "propertyText2" : "new Text",
    "propertyText3" : "new Text"
  }
}
```

Where it has a nested JSON object in it .

So instead of parsing that nested JSON , I want to store it as a string inside a parsed object.

object I am parsing into looks like this :

```
 public class SampleClass {
   public string regularProperty {get;set;}
   public string nestedJSON {get; set;}     
 }
```

So desired parsed object will contain nested JSON as a string:

```
SampleClass obj; 
obj.regularProperty = "Test here";
obj.nestedJSON = "{
"propertyText1" : "new Text",
"propertyText2" : "new Text",
"propertyText3" : "new Text"
}"
```

Any ideas how I can achieve that , or is it even possible ?

Comment: And how do you parse it? Can you add some code?

Comment: [Example based off the answer in the linked question](https://rextester.com/MGQ85562).

Comment: Using JRaw as a type solved that issue , thanks .